# Is there an SMP Server Command to change weather conditions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The latest version of Minecraft (1.5) brings, among other things, a number of different weather conditions.  Most of these annoy me to no end.  I tend to spend a lot of time playing on an SMP server, so I'm wondering if at least here, there is a way to effect changes in the weather: maybe through server commands?

Comment: I'm flagging an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because I feel that the newer question has a single, clear, vanilla answer that talks about both singleplayer and servers whereas this one, while it does have that answer, also has a bunch of "this is impossible" and "use a mod" answers caused by the question being asked prior to the introduction of `/weather`

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is.

As of 1.4.2, **`/weather`** (operators only) can be used to control the weather server-wide.

```
/weather clear
/weather rain
/weather thunder
```

You can also optionally specify the number of seconds, up to a million (that's 11 days and ~14 hours). For example, `/weather clear 60` will clear up the weather for 1 minute only.

Also, the **`/toggledownfall`** command (also ops only) stops/starts rain or snow on a vanilla server. It was added in a beta 1.9 pre-release.

Comment: Mind adding what version added this?  If it's more recent than 1.0.1, you may have angry downvoters and commenters saying it didn't work...

Comment: @John I don't really know, but I'll try to find out. It's in the latest stable (release 1.0.0; at least that's what the console says), so an angry mob shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: /toggledownfall no longer exists.

Answer (score 12):

Bukkit has integrated the commands into it.
You need OP but:

```
/weather sunny <time> 
/weather storm <time> 
/lighting <true/false> 
/thunder <true/false>
```

Comment: These appear to work for us, right on!

Answer (score 10):

<strike>There is no such command available in vanilla Minecraft servers, sorry.</strike>
See lunboks answer for more up-to-date info.

Comment: > Not to be rude at all, but the reason I'm asking this question is because there aren't any commands that **I know of** either.  :)  Can you confirm this somehow?

Comment: There are no documented commands or settings. Seeing as this is a brand new feature that's not surprising. If you want absolute certainty then [ask Mojang](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/weather_not_always_welcome_give_us_a_choice)

Comment: > *No documented commands or settings* is good enough for me!

Comment: It'd be a nice thing to have, though. Just yesterday I was building something in a thunderstorm and was ambushed by skeletons in the middle of the day. The irony? I was building a mob grinder!

Comment: If you're willing to use unofficial server software, I expect when CraftBukkit has been completely updated to 1.5, mods will surface that allow you to control the weather.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

On a vanilla server, you can use the command /toggledownfall to turn rain or snow (depending on what biome you are in) on and off (depending on whether or not it is currently raining/snowing) You must be an operator in order to use this command. It is possible to set your server so that toggling rain or snow is unable to be performed. This setting is not altered by an in-game command, but by an owner in the server's settings, much like the server's difficulty or whether or not flying is allowed. This command has no effect in the following biomes due to the biomes not allowing rain/snow: Desert, DesertHills, Hell, and Sky. The Hell biome is the only Biome present in The Nether, and the Sky biome is the only Biome present in The End.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/weather <sunny|rain|thunder|clear>`; I am not sure if you can make it snow or not. You can also use `/toggledownfall`. (All of this is as of 1.7.2.)