# Change the weather on vanilla SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an SMP Server Command to change weather conditions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20746/is-there-an-smp-server-command-to-change-weather-conditions)

Is there any command to change the weather on SMP, because sometime i just want to experiment with stuff and the rain gets in the way, and so is there any way **plugin** or command to do so? (NO BUKKIT PLEASE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as of Minecraft 1.0:**

Server operators can use the command `/toggledownfall` to start or stop rain-/snowfall.

**Original answer:**

Vanilla Minecraft has no command to change the weather. You'll need to install a mod of some kind.

However, it's difficult to recommend mods if you're set against Bukkit — it rather dominates the server mod scene. In fact, I wasn't able to find a non-Bukkit weather mod which is compatible with the current version of Minecraft.

Comment: you are **kind of** telling me what i already know...

Comment: Then why did you ask?

Comment: as in i need bukkit to change the weather but i want to know if that is possible in vanilla

Comment: Then I told you something you didn't know — weather can't be changed in vanilla.

Comment: so ok are you happy i did